# how to get security in wcf restfull service?

Tags: wcf, security

i am using  wcf restful services for .net application i want to know by default is it

provide security or we need to do explicitly if yes  please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option for security for the webHttpBinding is transport security (HTTPS/SSL). Authentication is also at the transport level but you have more options. This [MSDN reference lists the possible security options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924478.aspx) available to the binding. The information [in this MSDN forum entry shows the configuration of Basic authentication](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/35f8f628-565a-4aa2-a346-9754625c7324) for the webHttpBinding.